# Display amount of entries by one user SQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table which stores issues logged by users, I want to loop through the table and do a count of the amount of issues logged by each user and then display this in an HTML table. Here is what I so far but it only works for one entry and then doesn't work.

```
    <div class ="col-md-4">
        <?php
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT analyst_name FROM escalations");
                echo "<table class='table'>
                <tr>
                    <th>Analyst</th>
                    <th>Issues Logged</th>
                </tr>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
            $analyst = $row['analyst_name'];
            $issuesLogged = count($analyst);

            echo "<td>" . $analyst . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $issuesLogged . "</td>";
            ?>
        <?php 
        echo "</tr>";

        echo "</table>";
        }
        ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're better off doing the count in SQL:

```
SELECT analyst_name, count(issuesLogged) as issue_total FROM escalations GROUP BY analyst_name
```